# get method using RKObjectManager instead of RKRequestOperation - RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

Below is the function which uses RKObjectRequestOperation for get method how to write the same using RKObjectManager

```
 NSString *hostName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self getHostName]];

NSString *urls = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/randomcollection/%@/0/%li",hostName,profileId,(long)noOfItems];


RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [MappingProvider collectionMapping ];


RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urls];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly timeoutInterval:90.0f];
[request setValue:[GameManager sharedInstance].authenticatedUser.appTokenId forHTTPHeaderField:@"tokenId"];

RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];


[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    if (success) {
        RKLogInfo(@"Load collection: %@", mappingResult.array);
    }
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    if (failure) {
        failure(operation, error);
    }

}];

[objectRequestOperation start];
```

Edit: Here's what I have tried it gives me error of *** Assertion failure in -[RKRouter URLWithRoute:object:]

```
      NSString *hostName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self getHostName]];  
   NSString* urls = [[NSString alloc]      initWithFormat:@"%@/userprofile/selectbyid/%@",hostName,profileId];

 RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urls]];
    [manager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"tokenId" value:[GameManager sharedInstance].authenticatedUser.appTokenId];

RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [MappingProvider userProfileRespMapping ];


    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


    UserProfile * modelObject = [[UserProfile alloc] init];
    [modelObject setProfileId:profileId];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObject:modelObject
                                          path:nil
                                    parameters:nil
                                       success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                  if (success) {
                                                       RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Userprofiles: %@", mappingResult.array);
                                                       NSLog(@"Mapping Results %@",[mappingResult.array firstObject]);
                                                    UserProfile *currentUserProfile = (UserProfile *)[mappingResult.array firstObject];
                                                       success(currentUserProfile);
                                                   }
                                       }
                                       failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                        if (failure) {
                                                       RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
                                                       failure(operation, error);
                                                   }
                                       }];
```

Comment: Try writing the object manager version, if it doesn't work show what you tried and explain what it does wrong

Comment: @ok wain I will write down edit the quesiton

Comment: @Wain : please check the above function i have wrote it gives me error at route function

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. It should look like this. This will give you a starting point. For a more detailed answer you should concretize your question.

```
// Initial setup
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your base url"]];

RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:modelClass];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"sourceProperty" : @"destinationProperty"}];

[manager addResponseDescriptor:
               [RKResponseDescriptor
                   responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                          method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                     pathPattern:@"yourPath"
                                         keyPath:@"jsonStructureDepending"
                                     statusCodes:
                                         RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(
                                             RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];

[[manager router].routeSet
                addRoutes:@[
                       [RKRoute routeWithClass:[model class]
                                   pathPattern:@"yourPath"
                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET]];


//Within your controller or elsewhere
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObject:modelObject
                                      path:nil
                                parameters:nil
                                   success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                   }
                                   failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                   }];
```

Comment: thanks I have tried based on this kindly check my edited question I am getting error at route function

Comment: I've updated my answer forgot to mention that you need to add a route if you want to **get** via the modelObject.